# Keyboard shortcut for Visual Studio/Resharper tooltips?

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, resharper

Is there a keyboard shortcut to display tooltips provided by Visual Studio & Resharper when you hover over a bit of code?  I'm already aware of Quick Documentation (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>) and Quick Watch (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do you mean <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>? This is the command `Edit.Quickinfo`.

(sorry, I am unable to add a comment with the PC I have now)
For the single variable, do you mean in debug mode ?

2nd Edit: I think VS names these tooltips 'datatips'. Unfortunately, there is no command to show them, so no possible shortcut.

Comment: Yup, that's half of it.  How about for the tooltip that inspects a single variable?  Similar to Quick Watch but not in the annoying pop-up window.

Comment: Confirmed.  DataTips do not have shortcut keys.  

" For example, DataTips are a feature designed to allow easy debugging access to variables by mousing over variable names in the text editor. While it is possible to access debugging information about variables using other methods accessible using only the keyboard, DataTips do not have keyboard shortcuts."

http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/5/c/15c33baa-1cee-431a-a8c0-8d521bda6b9a/Microsoft%20Visual%20Studio%202008%20VPAT.doc

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by binding this command to a key:

EditorContextMenus.CodeWindow.PinToSource

Unfortunately it works with what you have selected, not with what you are hovering over. Not only do you have to do the extra click, but you need to select the entire variable name and all of its prefixes as well.

Old question but useful to know.

My shortcuts:

PinToSource set to alt-F1

ClearAllDataTips set to shift-alt-F1

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>

It is equivalent to
<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>